# How to eliminate duplicates in a struct, and use qsort to sort them in C

Tags: c, sorting, struct, c89

I am trying to find people in my struct from a specific country, eliminate duplicates and sort the remainders after team and name with qsort.

My struct is as following:

```
struct rider_info{
  char race_name[30];
  char name[50];
  char lastname[30];
  int age;
  char team[4];
  char country[4];
  };
```

So some of the people in the file i am reading into my struct appears in multiple races. I therefore need to eliminate duplicates but i am not sure how that is done. And thereafter i need to sort those people with qsort after team and name. I have made a try but it just printed all the people from that specific country i needed. Here is the code as it is at this point:

```
void print_belgian_riders(FILE *fp, int j, rider_info person[j]) {
  char str[4] = "BEL"; //i need to print Belgian riders
  char line[128];
  int lines = count_lines();    
  for (j = 0; j < lines; ++j) {
      if (strcmp(person[j].country, str) == 0) {
          qsort(person, 20, sizeof(person), struct_comp_team);
          printf("%s %s %d %s %s ",
               person[j].name,
               person[j].lastname,
               person[j].age,
               person[j].team,
               person[j].country);
               printf("\n");

      }

   }
}
```

And here is my compare function for sorting after team and name:

```
int struct_comp_team(const void *ep1, const void *ep2) {
  int TeamSort = strcmp((((rider_info*)ep1)->team), ((rider_info*)ep2)->team);
  int lastNameSort = strcmp(((rider_info*)ep1)->lastname, ((rider_info*)ep2)->lastname);

  if (TeamSort != 0) {
      return (TeamSort);

  } 
  else if (lastNameSort != 0) {
      return lastNameSort;
  }
}
```

My compare function is not working, and i am not sure what is wrong with it, does anybody have an idea about how to do it? Is there also someone who had an idea about how i should eliminate duplicates?

Comment: your function does not return anything if `TeamSort` and `lastNameSort` are both `0`.

Comment: Check your syntax, `rider_info person[j]` is very very strange in the function prototype. Use `-Werror` and `-Wall`

Comment: Note that it would be better not to compare names if the teams are different, unless you're in an environment where the operations should all take the same time to minimize the options on timing attacks (but even then, there'd be other issues to worry about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your compare function as per `mch` advice.

```
int struct_comp_team(const void *ep1, const void *ep2) {
  int TeamSort = strcmp((((rider_info*)ep1)->team), ((rider_info*)ep2)->team);
  int lastNameSort = strcmp(((rider_info*)ep1)->lastname, ((rider_info*)ep2)->lastname);

  if (TeamSort != 0) {
      return (TeamSort);

  } 
  else if (lastNameSort != 0) {
      return lastNameSort;
  }
  return 0;//duplicate value
}
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to move `int lastNameSort = strcmp(... ` into the `else` code block, and adapt the `if` you show in the `else` of course,

Comment: @WeatherVane, True. Left it for CHr_fred. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I tried all your suggestion out, but when i run the function nothing is sorted, and my struct is just printed as originally. I do not really know what is wrong?

Comment: @CHr_fred, put some print statement and see the value in the above function. Print the value of both team and lastname and try to understand why they are failing

Comment: Time to use a debugger like `gdb`